# Bluetooth HSF/HSP headset issue

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I googled for days and did all the "it works on my machine" solutions I've found but the problem is still there.
Let me explain: almost every time I connect my Bluetooth headset, Ubuntu automatically selects "HSF/HSP" as configuration. Apparently, this happens because it recognizes them as *mono + mic*, but they are *stereo + mic*. The thing is: with the pre-selected setting the audio is very bad, it's muffled/distorted/low.

I can manually switch it to A2DP, when it's not (randomly) pre-selected by the OS, but it's really bothering me. Is there a way to disable it at all? I don't need it.
Sorry to ask even though it's a well-known problem, but all the workaround I have found didn't work.

Also: if it's so bad, I don't really understand why the devs don't remove it completely...

Comment: Is is working correctly you have a device that has sound and mic that is the profile it needs. The profile you want is for no mic.

Comment: @David I want to have control at least of the default setting. I don't like the fact that I've to manually switch it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first disable the HSP/HSF profile if you're not using a mic.

In `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` (create it if it doesn't exist), add this line to the `[General]` section:

```
Disable=Headset
```

Then restart the bluetooth service via :

```
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Now we need to disable auto switching to HSP profile on call events, because call apps like discord or teams will want to switch to it, since it's not there, you'll just not get any sound, as if you have no audio devices.

You'll need to go to the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and find:

```
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
```

and modify it to

```
load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=false
```

Then restart pulseaudio through :

```
pulseaudio -k
```

if pulseaudio isn't completely killed, check if there are still processes using it via:

```
fuser -v /dev/snd/*
```

Finally restart the service

```
systemctl restart pulseaudio.service
```